# add remove <li with textbox on button click. (out of ul wrap problem) and name inputs uniquely

Tags: javascript, html, forms, insert, click

I have an issue with js. I have form like below. Add button is adding li with input box and Remove button is removing... it is working very well. the issue is, it is creating the li after ul, out of ul :/ you can see it clearly at the screenshot below. any idea about solution? appreciate!!! thanks!!!

*

> ps, how can I name the created inputs
>   unique? now all has same name which is
>   txt :/

*

---

**JS CODE**

```
function addTextBox() {
    var form = document.contact;
    form.appendChild(document.createElement('li')).innerHTML = "Name <input type=\"text\" name=\"txt\" class=\"txt_input required\">";
}
```

---

**HTML CODE:**

```
                        <li id="persons_add"><label for="persons"># of Persons Attending: *</label>

                    <table width="40%" border="1">
                        <tr>
                            <td><input type="text" name="count" value="0" class="txt_input required" style="width:20px;"  readonly ></td>
                            <td><INPUT type="button" value="ADD" name="add" onClick="incrementCount()"></td>
                            <td><INPUT type="button" value="Remove" name="remove" onClick="decCount()"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>

                    </li>
                    <li class="alignRight"><input type="submit" value="Register" id="btnsend" name="btnsend" class="btn_submit" /></li>
                </ul>
```

---

**SCREENSHOT of issue**

[alt text http://xs1144.xs.to/xs1144/09434/buuu851.jpg](http://xs1144.xs.to/xs1144/09434/buuu851.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't you to append the "li" to the "ul" instead of the form ?

```
function addTextBox() {
    var myUl = document.getElementById('`___your_ul_id____`'); **<--- change this**
    myUl.appendChild(document.createElement('li')).innerHTML = "Name <input type=\"text\" name=\"txt\" class=\"txt_input required\">";
}
```

Comment: aaa silly me! of course! thanks. working great now : ) and how can I unique name the created textbox? now all name is txt :(

Answer (score 1):

You need to append the new li to the ul, not the form element.

```
var ul = document.getElementById("ul_id");
ul.appendChild(document.createElement('li')).innerHTML = "Name <input type=\"text\" name=\"txt\" class=\"txt_input required\">";
```

Answer (score 0):

Call appendChild on the UL element, not the form element.